# How to set piston's block direction with custom super flat preset in Minecraft 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to create a custom super flat preset in Minecraft and when I try to have a piston layer they all point north. In the code, how would I make them face up?

Comment: From the [wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Superflat#Preset_code_format) it seems like you can't. But that would be very strange, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @FabianRöling I ran into the same problem and I agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think that it's possible. things like block directions are all handled in their physical blockstates, and the preset code using in superflat generation doesn't have any handlers for that. as such, when you specify blocks like that, it'll use their default direction blockstate of north.